# How to return File with custom Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I use *HttpResponseMessage* to return a file to front-end :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string version, string environment,
string filetype)
{
    var path = @"C:\Temp\a.txt";
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    return result;
}
```

The question is how can i also return message along with the file ?I thought it has limit if adding the message to custom header .

**Edit :**

The use-case here is the action will create a lot of files , zip the files and return the zip file to front-end , but the problem is the some of the files are not successfully created i need to return the file names to front-end , i can create logs in database but the question is the front-end doesn't know the log id or some other info to identify the specific log.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simple answer is: You can't.

`Content-Type: application/octet-stream`
sets the, well, content type, and as such the browser will assume that the bytes that are part of the content are a binary file.

What is the use-case here?
Maybe you *can* use Multipart, as is used for E-Mails, but in general just having separate requests/endpoints would be the typical solution. You could even append a query parameter such as `?message` to the existing endpoint

Comment: Yeah, but when using json, it's not a simple file download anymore, it also needs to be encoded and decoded and then offered as a download from the local storage/a blob. 

All for what should supposedly be multiple routes. Doing different can be achieved, sure, but has a lot of downstream problems, e.g. that the custom messages won't be cached by a proxy anymore, which would make sense for file downloads, etc

Comment: the use-case here is the action will create a lot of files , zip the files and return the zip file to front-end , but the problem is the some of the files are not successfully created i need to return the file names to front-end , i can create logs in database but the question is the front-end doesn't know the log id or some other info to identify the specific log.

Comment: Well then I would use some "prepare" route, that starts the zipping and maybe returns the list of files, the successful ones or the errorneous ones and then can use a redirect and/or return some temporary file id (you should use UUIDs or something for them and really delete them after some time).

The resulting file id is then the second route/call, the one to download the zip.
The information about the zipping failing is just not part of the file, but rather the process of requesting/creating it

Comment: Yes , different request is a choice . I would know is it a good idea to add custom response header with the log file path ? then i can log the errors to log file ? The idea is  if front-end not get the request header , it won't send a send request to get the errors

Comment: Not really, because logfiles shouldn't be accessible by the whole web and so you don't need to store the errors in a log file at all, but can directly send them back to the frontend and forget about it on the server, with the different request. Then the frontend can even handle that differently: critical file missing - start the download? try again?